# Which python gui library to use to create dock application?

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, svg, dock

I would like to make a docking application using Python to run on Linux, but i have not enough insights / experience to chose the right GUI library. The requirements are:

- The dock should be borderless.
- The background should be transparent and / or customisable with SVG themes.
- It should import icons in SVG format.
- It should be able to produce few effects (nothing too fancy though) e.g. apha-fade in/out or window sliding in/out.
- The dock should have a special behaviour on the desktop (eg. always on top, reserved space etc. i.e. typical dock behaviour.)

I've had a look at GTK, Qt, WX, Tkinter (the latter seems inappropriate) but I am not sure what to use. Could you please tell me what library is best fit for this kind of interface and what functions/documentation i should be looking for?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i found out that Qt (using PyQt4) should be able to do this. It has a special library to handle SVG images and it seems to be possible to theme the entire GUI without using another library. See PyQt4 documentation [over here](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyqtbook.html).